# Git for Windows: grep returning nothing for any search

Tags: windows, git, grep

`$ cat > test
something
[Ctrl+C]
$ grep something .
grep: .: Is a directory`

Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 64-bit

`$ git --version
git version 2.13.2.windows.1`

No matter what I search for it doesn't find the text even if the word is in one or many files. I remember it working on older versions of Git for Windows.

Comment: This works on my Windows 10, `grep -s something ./*` where the `-s` means suppress error messages like the `Is a Directory`. There is also some more information in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426363/how-can-i-have-grep-not-print-out-no-such-file-or-directory-errors#6426401)

Comment: Interesting output; not sure why I need ./* and just . doesn't work as I remember it always working with grep:
`$ grep -s something ./*
./page-contact.php:        <h4 class="text-center">Looking for something else?</h4>`
`$ grep something ./*
grep: ./assets: Is a directory
grep: ./dist: Is a directory
grep: ./lang: Is a directory
grep: ./lib: Is a directory
./page-contact.php:        <h4 class="text-center">Looking for something else?</h4>
grep: ./templates: Is a directory`
`$ grep something .
grep: .: Is a directory`

Comment: I had a similar thing happen where I was using GitBash and the grep command to search for something. Wouldn't return anything. Fired up MSYS2, used the same command, and found values. I've had issues with GitBash not working as intended with other things recently.